# How to write a regex which ignores a partial match?

Tags: javascript

Imagine this markdown file:

```
...

## Questions heading
### Question sub-heading
- some question
- some question
### Question sub-heading
- some question

## Next section heading
- blah
- blah

## Another section heading
- blah
- blah
```

I need to be able to extract all of the questions in the **Questions** section, which may sometimes include **Question sub-headings**.

My regex is working only if a `sub-heading doesn't exist`. Here is my current regex: `##\sQuestions([\s\S]*?)##` which for the above example would return this:

```
## Questions heading
##
```

I need it to return the entire section between the two main headings. Which should look like this:

```
### Question sub-heading
- some question
- some question
### Question sub-heading
- some question
```

I need to ignore sub-headings a.k.a `###` as those are not main section headings and continue matching until the next main section heading begins, which is denoted as `##`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, I'm not saying it's pretty but it will work:

```
/^##\s*Questions.*?\n([^]*?)^##[^#]/m
```

Test:

```
var match = `## Questions heading
### Question sub-heading
- some question
- some question
### Question sub-heading
- some question

## Next section heading
- blah
- blah

## Another section heading
- blah
- blah`.match(/^##\s*Questions.*?\n([^]*?)^##[^#]/m);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

It's relying on that `##` is at the beginning of the line.

Breakdown:

```
/
  ^##\s*Questions.*?\n # Match "## Questions ...\n"
  ([^]*?)              # Match anything including newline
  ^##[^#]              # Match "## ..."
/m                     # Make `^` and `$` work on each line instead of all input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `\n##` only whenever it is not followed by another `#` by appending `(?!#)`:

`##\sQuestions([\s\S]*?)\n##(?!#)`

Note that you need to match `\n##` instead of just `##`. Without matching the newline, the regular expression can still match `###`: the first `#` will be matched as part of `[\s\S]`.